# Using Docker and Symfony with several database connections

Tags: docker, symfony, orm, database-connection

I am working on a project that was implemented with MAMP.
I'm in the process of changing the setup to Docker.

The project uses several database connections defined in config/packages/doctrine.yaml:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: db1
    connections:
        # connection to db1 database
        db1:
            host: '%env(DB1_POSTGRESQL_HOST)%'
            user: '%env(DB1_POSTGRESQL_USER)%'
            password: '%env(DB1_POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD)%'
            port: '%env(DB1_POSTGRESQL_PORT)%'
            dbname: '%env(DB1_POSTGRESQL_NAME)%'
            driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
            server_version: '%env(DB1_POSTGRESQL_SERVER_VERSION)%'
            charset: '%env(DB1_POSTGRESQL_CHARSET)%'

        # connection to db2 database
        db2:
            host: '%env(DB2_POSTGRESQL_HOST)%'
            user: '%env(DB2_POSTGRESQL_USER)%'
            password: '%env(DB2_POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD)%'
            port: '%env(DB2_POSTGRESQL_PORT)%'
            dbname: '%env(DB2_POSTGRESQL_NAME)%'
            driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
            server_version: '%env(DB2_POSTGRESQL_SERVER_VERSION)%'
            charset: '%env(DB2_POSTGRESQL_CHARSET)%'
```

And the connection data are stored in .env:

```
# DB1 postgreSQL config
DB1_POSTGRESQL_HOST=localhost
DB1_POSTGRESQL_PORT=5432
DB1_POSTGRESQL_NAME=XXXXX
DB1_POSTGRESQL_USER=YYYYY
DB1_POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=
DB1_POSTGRESQL_SERVER_VERSION=11.0
DB1_POSTGRESQL_CHARSET=utf8

# DB2 postgreSQL config
DB2_POSTGRESQL_HOST=localhost
DB2_POSTGRESQL_PORT=5433
DB2_POSTGRESQL_NAME=ZZZZZZ
DB2_POSTGRESQL_USER=VVVVVV
DB2_POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=
DB2_POSTGRESQL_SERVER_VERSION=11.0
DB2_POSTGRESQL_CHARSET=utf8de here
```

I also have the dumps of the databases.

How can I implement it in docker-compose.yml so that the database is initially created but the connections also work later in the project.

```
postgres:
  image: postgres
  container_name: postgres
  ports:
    - '5433:5432'
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    - POSTGRES_DB=XXXXX
    - POSTGRES_USER=YYYYYY
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ZZZZZZ
  volumes:
    - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/dataode here
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that - here db1 and db2 are 2 different hosts that would be resolved automatically if your php-app is also in docker
otherwise you can change hostname to your machine name where database docker containers are running & change port to 7777 / 7778 also.
If everything is in docker on the same host then you can use as given below.

```
# global DB1 postgreSQL config
GLOBAL_POSTGRESQL_HOST=db1
GLOBAL_POSTGRESQL_PORT=5432
GLOBAL_POSTGRESQL_NAME=XXXXX
GLOBAL_POSTGRESQL_USER=YYYYY
GLOBAL_POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=ZZZZZZZZ
GLOBAL_POSTGRESQL_SERVER_VERSION=11.0
GLOBAL_POSTGRESQL_CHARSET=utf8

# global DB2 postgreSQL config
GLOBAL_PIC_POSTGRESQL_HOST=db2
GLOBAL_PIC_POSTGRESQL_PORT=5432
GLOBAL_PIC_POSTGRESQL_NAME=XXXXX
GLOBAL_PIC_POSTGRESQL_USER=YYYYY
GLOBAL_PIC_POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=ZZZZZZZZ
GLOBAL_PIC_POSTGRESQL_SERVER_VERSION=11.0
GLOBAL_PIC_POSTGRESQL_CHARSET=utf8de here
```

and also change adapt docker-compose.yml accordingly.

```
db1:
  image: postgres
  container_name: postgres-db1
  ports:
    - '7777:5432'
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    - POSTGRES_DB=XXXX
    - POSTGRES_USER=YYYYY
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ZZZZZ
  volumes:
    - db1-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/dataode 
    
db2:
  image: postgres
  container_name: postgres-db2
  ports:
    - '7778:5432'
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    - POSTGRES_DB=XXXXX
    - POSTGRES_USER=YYYYYY
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ZZZZ
  volumes:
    - db2-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/dataode
```